# Rails make database mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite

I'm using Rails 3, and Ubuntu. I want to change the default Rails SQLite3 into a mysql database. I ran these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client libmysqlclient15-dev
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby1.8
```

These were successful. Then I did this in the gemfile

```
#gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql'
```

This worked, now, what else should I do to complete the MySQL setup. I know for one the database.yml needs to change, but how does it need to look for Ubuntu and how do I fill in the parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your config/database.yml must look like :

```
base: &base
  adapter: mysql
  username: YourUserName
  password: YourPassword
  host: localhost
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
development:
  database: YourApp_dev
  <<: *base
test:
  database: YourApp_test
  <<: *base
production:
  database: YourApp_prod
  <<: *base
```

Comment: is user, my username for my ubuntu machine when im logging on? Is password my password that i chose when i installed the mysql server?

Comment: The username and the password must be the ones you use to log to your mysql server

Comment: No, they are your mysql user credentials.  not OS specific

Comment: there are options to set them and have them match your login, please see the mysql site to read up on the info for this

Comment: I was never prompted to make a username, but i was for a password when installing the server. How do i retrieve the user

Comment: Try "root". I think it's the default

Comment: The database: -- fields I used Amapp, because that's what i named my application, but if i run rake db:migrate, i get rake aborted!
Unknown database 'Amapp'

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: I guess it's Amapp_dev and you must run a db:create before (to create the database)

Answer (score 0):

Is the database on the same host?

You need to log into mysql, set a user, create a database.  If the database is on a database server, outside of the application server, then you will need to make accessible from the net.

http://www.slac.stanford.edu/BFROOT/www/Computing/Online/Databases/CfgDB/CfgDB-MySQL-Setup.html

After you're done setting up the database (not just installing it), then you're database.yml files need to be modified per the above.